# how can i use floatLayout inside stacklayout

Tags: python, kivy

I am making an app in which, on one screen, I want buttons stacked along the right edge of the screen(for which I need stack layout) and 2 buttons at the centre of the screen(for this I want to use float layout). I have searched for it but nowhere I can see any examples of using two different layouts on one screen.

Can we use two different layouts on a screen? if yes how can we do that?

hers a sample code-

```
    from kivy.uix.stacklayout import StackLayout
    from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
    from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen 

    class screen_1(Screen,Stacklayout): ''' here I tried to inherit 
                                            floatlayout, but i guess it 
                                            doesnt work that way'''
        pass

    class main(App):
        def build(self):
            return screen_1()

    m = main()
    m.run()
```

kivy code-

```
    <screen_1>:
        StackLayout:
            orientation: 'tb-rl'
            spacing: 10
            padding: 90
            TextInput:
                text: "write your word here"
                color: 1,1,1,1
                id: word_input
                width: 300
                size_hint: None, .10
            stackLayout:
                orientation: 'rl-tb'
                spacing: 10
                padding: 90
                TextInput:
                    text: "write your word here"
                    color: 1,1,1,1
```

Answer (score 0):

Layouts, lake all widgets, can be nested.

If you want two layouts in your screen, you just put them in an appropriate layout to manage their respective size/positions.

First, you likely don't want to do multiple-inheritance with widgets, at least not inheriting from multiple widgets (inheriting from one widget and one or multiple other objects can be fine, but inheriting from multiple widgets will cause issues). Also, `Screen` is already a `RelativeLayout`[1] which is almost the same as a `FloatLayout` (only it makes the `pos` coordinates of children relative to its own).

Instead, what you want is to compose (by nesting).

```
Screen:
    StackLayout:
        size_hint: .5, 1  # let's take half of the screen in width, and all of it in height
        # whatever you want inside this layout
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint: .5, 1 # same, half of the width, all of the height
        pos_hint: {'right': 1} # stick to the right of the screen
        Button:
```

[1] https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html?highlight=screen#kivy.uix.screenmanager.Screen
[2] https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.relativelayout.html#kivy.uix.relativelayout.RelativeLayout